# Label do dataframe gerando problemas quando computado a média

Tags: python

O problema é o seguinte. Estou fazendo um programa aonde o usuário vai inserir um dataframe de dimensões 2 linhas e 1 coluna (ele pode ter inúmeras linhas) e realizar alguns cálculos, um deles é a média. Para o calculo dela, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def two_m(I_barra, rm_barra, tabela_cep):
    # Computing ICL, UCL, CL 
    UCL_I_Chart = (I_barra + (tabela_cep.iloc[0][0]*rm_barra))
    ICL_I_Chart = (I_barra - (tabela_cep.iloc[0][0]*rm_barra))
    CL_I_Chart = I_barra
    
    standard_dev_I_1_positive = (
        ((UCL_I_Chart-CL_I_Chart)/3) + CL_I_Chart)
    
    standard_dev_I_2_positive = (
        ((UCL_I_Chart-CL_I_Chart)/3) + standard_dev_I_1_positive)
    
    standard_dev_I_2_negative = (
        ((CL_I_Chart-ICL_I_Chart)/3) + ICL_I_Chart)
    
    standard_dev_I_1_negative = (
        ((CL_I_Chart-ICL_I_Chart)/3) + standard_dev_I_2_negative)
    
    df_I_control_chart = {
        'UCL': [UCL_I_Chart],
        'CL': [CL_I_Chart],
        'ICL': [ICL_I_Chart],
        '1 x S(+)': [standard_dev_I_1_positive],
        '2 x S(+)': [standard_dev_I_2_positive],
        '1 x S(-)': [standard_dev_I_1_negative],
        '2 x S(-)': [standard_dev_I_2_negative]
    }

    print(df_I_control_chart)

lista = [132,135]
df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns = ['X'])
df.index +=1
I_barra = df.mean()

# Compute of MR:
m_r_array = df.to_numpy()  # Convert df to numpy
saida = m_r_array - np.roll(m_r_array, 1)  # Vector subtraction
saida[0] = m_r_array[0]  # Copy the first entry to the exit
rm_data = np.abs(saida)  # Transform de negative values to positive
new_rm_df = rm_data.tolist()  # Transform the array to list
new_rm_df.pop(0)  # Remove the first element of the list
rm_barra = np.mean(new_rm_df)  # Compute the mean of Rm

data ={
    'E2': [2.660, 1.772, 1.457, 1.290,
           1.184, 1.109, 1.054, 1.010,
           0.975, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0  
    ]
}

tabela_cep = pd.DataFrame(data)

if df.shape[0] == 2:
  two_m(I_barra, rm_barra, tabela_cep)
```

o resultado está me gerando uma series (até ai tudo bem) entretanto, essa series está gerando problemas nos próximos cálculos que necessitam da variável `I_barra`. Não sei como, mas se eu tiver um próximo calculo que necessita da variável `I_barra` ele simplesmente está inserindo o index da series junto com o cálculo e ficando uma coisa bugada, segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvido. Troquei o `df.mean()` por `new_df = df['X'].mean()` e os cálculos retornaram valores sem o `X` incluso.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).